# Java - Return different child classes based on input parameters

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Given these classes:

```
public class VersionVOV1 extends BaseVO {

    private String fieldOne = null;

    public String getFieldOne() {
        return fieldOne;
    }
    public void setFieldOne(String fieldOne) {
        this.fieldOne = fieldOne;
}

public class VersionVOV2 extends BaseVO {

    private String fieldFour = null;

    public String getFieldFour() {
        return fieldFour;
    }
    public void setFieldFour(String fieldFour) {
        this.fieldFour = fieldFour;
    }

}

public class BaseVO {

   // common code here

}
```

I have a calling method `doSomething` which returns a specific child class based upon an input string:

```
public BaseVO doSomething(String version) {

    BaseVO versionVO =  doSomethingVersioned(createVersionVO(version));

    return versionVO;
}
```

The remaining methods are:

```
private BaseVO createVersionVO(String version) {

    BaseVO versionVO = null;

    if (version.equalsIgnoreCase("V1")) {

        versionVO = new VersionVOV1();

    } else if (version.equalsIgnoreCase("V2"))

        versionVO = new VersionVOV2();

    return versionVO;
}

protected VersionVOV1 doSomethingVersioned(VersionVOV1 versionVO) throws Exception {

    versionVO.setFieldOne("The versionVO is of type: " + versionVO.getClass());
    versionVO.setFieldTwo("Field two");
    versionVO.setFieldThree("Field three");

    return versionVO;

}

protected VersionVOV2 doSomethingVersioned(VersionVOV2 versionVO) throws Exception {

    versionVO.setFieldOne("The versionVO is of type: " + versionVO.getClass());
    versionVO.setFieldThree("Field three");
    versionVO.setFieldFour("Field four");

    return versionVO;

}
```

As you can see I've overridden `doSomethingVersioned` to take in a specific child class.  My problem however lies with the compilation error that looks like this on `doSomethingVersioned`:  **The method doSomethingVersioned(VersionVOV1) in the type VersionExample is not applicable for the arguments (BaseVO).**

I've tried returning a type of `<T extends BaseVO>` from `createVersionVO` but then I get other compilation errors in that method stating **Type mismatch: cannot convert from VersionVOV1 to T**.

I feel like this should be easier than I'm making it.   How can I keep this overall pattern but allow this to compile?

Thanks to everyone who helps!

Comment: Use generics ! They are your friend !

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the pattern [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Note: there really is no benefit from genericity here. You are merely creating something then the presumption is it will go on its way. Generics tend to yield the greatest benefit when you are wanting to leverage code that is orthogonal to the domain objects, e.g. collections.

Comment: Well, isn't a factory method essentially what I have with my createVersionVO method?  I'm passing in the particular version of the class I want and returning it.